# Trigger.io running app on android emulator says "Unfortunately app has stopped working"

Tags: android, android-emulator, trigger.io, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to run the trigger.io "Hello world" app on the Android Emulator but with no success. I tried different emulated devices but nothing worked. When I deployed it to a real device it worked.

Here's the logcat from the emulator:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1218): Start proc io.trigger.forge1c78fd5c0b6611e4977712313b0234c0 for activity io.trigger.forge1c78fd5c0b6611e4977712313b0234c0/io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity: pid=1629 ui
E/WebViewFactory( 1629): Chromium WebView does not exist
E/WebViewFactory( 1629): Chromium WebView does not exist
D/AndroidRuntime( 1629): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1629): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2dfcce8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1629): Process: io.trigger.forge1c78fd5c0b6611e4977712313b0234c0, PID: 1629
E/AndroidRuntime( 1629): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.trigger.forge1c78fd5c0b6611e4977712313b0234c0/io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity}: java.lang.Unsuppo
```

I guess that "Chromium WebView does not exist" is not a good thing so I googled it but couldn't find anything useful regarding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use genymotion VM to test your app.
Just create free account over there and then download and install. Run the genymotion device and then eclipse auto detect that device. Test on that. Genymotion is much faster and better then the default eclipse Emulator device.

[www.genymotion.com](http://www.genymotion.com)

Comment: Even tho it's not actually solving the problem described, the tool you provided does work for me and that's why I'm marking your answer as a correct one. Cheers!

Comment: Ohhh thnq...

But if you are using any additional library then must install gapps package to the Genymotion device like if you are using google play service in your project then u need to install gapps package to your genymotion device

visit this link once
http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/install-android-4-4-2-kitkat-pc.html
if that can make your problem solved.